# Maximum execution time with Laravel and LocalStack

Tags: php, laravel, localstack

I'm trying to use Localstack to mock an s3 instance so that I can upload images from a form.
Here's  my docker-compose:

```
localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    container_name: localstack
    environment: 
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
      - SERVICES=s3
      - DEBUG=1
      - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock      
    ports: 
      - "4566:4566"
    volumes: 
      - "${TEMPDIR:-/tmp/localstack}:/tmp/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

My laravel filesystems.php looks like this:

```
's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
        ],
```

And my envfile:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=localstack
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=localstack
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=catering-management
AWS_ENDPOINT=http://s3.localhost:4566
```

I tried 2 methods, the first one just saves on my local storage:

```
$path = Storage::putFileAs(
    '/'.auth()->user()->tenant_id, $request->file('media_name'),
    $request->file('media_name')->getClientOriginalName()
);
```

The second method, which seems the one that tries to connect to localstack is:

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put(auth()->user()->tenant_id.'/', $request->file('media_name'));
```

Only that it hangs until "Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded" is thrown.

What am I doing wrong here? Any hint?

Thank you very much

EDIT:

So it looks like a problem with lavarel itself. Any HTTP call to any other service on localhost times out using GuzzleHttp client.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS S3 URL is different from the original one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54825127/aws-s3-url-is-different-from-the-original-one)

Comment: Is a duplicate, as per self answer

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the solution. After setting up a nodejs server doing exactly the same thing, I quickly found out about the 's3ForcePathStyle' flag. Took me hours to find the equivalent in PHP. Just add the property:

```
'use_path_style_endpoint' => true
```

to filesystems.php.

All merits to https://stackoverflow.com/a/54826384/3353167