# Minio with laravel, bucket name prefixed as a subdomain on a local server

Tags: laravel, docker-compose, laravel-8, minio

I'am using minio for file storage, also i've configured it all using docker-compose. My laravel filesystem configuration file looks like this.

```
's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => '',
        'secret' => '',
        'region' => 'ap-southeast-1',
        'bucket' => 'students',
        'endpoint' => 'http://minio:9000',
    ]
```

I can access minio web dashboard using http://minio:9000. But while storing an object I'm encountering following errors.

```
// code to store file
Storage::disk('s3')->put($bucketFolder . $name, file_get_contents($file));

//Exception thrown
Error executing "PutObject" on "http://students.minio:9000/misc/1641374889-1033010763.png"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: students.minio (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://students.minio:9000/misc/1641374889-1033010763.png
```

I don't why *students*. is being added to the endpoint url.

Answer (score 4):

I got it right by modifying config.php like below. If anyone has other options please suggest.

```
's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => '',
        'secret' => '',
        'region' => 'ap-southeast-1',
        'bucket' => 'students',
        'bucket_endpoint' => true, // added
        'endpoint' => 'http://minio:9000/students',
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrived at similar problem in golang where there is config property `S3ForcePathStyle`

```
s3Config := &aws.Config{
    Credentials: credentials.NewStaticCredentials(apiKey, apiSecret, ""),
    Endpoint:         "http://minio:9000",
    Region:           "ap-southeast-1",
    S3ForcePathStyle: aws.Bool(true), // bool pointer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This did not work for me:

```
'bucket_endpoint' => true
```

Instead this worked:

```
'use_path_style_endpoint' => true,
```

I got it from here: [Maximum execution time with Laravel and LocalStack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69487066/maximum-execution-time-with-laravel-and-localstack)